# Unable to slice year from date column using negative indexing with pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, slice

I have a simple data set, where we have a Dates column from which I want to extract the year. 
I am using the negative index to get the year

d0['Year'] = d0['Dates'].apply(lambda x: x[-1:-5])

This normally works, however, not on this. A blank column is created. 
I sampled the column for some of the data and saw no odd characters present. 
I have tried the following variations

d0['Year'] = d0['Dates'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[-1:-5])  # column is created and it is blank.

d0['Year'] = d0.Dates.str.extract('\d{4}') # gives an error "ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups"

d0['Year'] = d0['Dates'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]','a')[-1:-5]) # same - gives a blank column

Really not sure what other options I have and where is the issue. 
What possibly can be the issue?

Below is a sample dump of the data I have

Outbreak,Dates,Region,Tornadoes,Fatalities,Notes
2000 Southwest Georgia tornado outbreak,"February 13–14, 2000",Georgia,17,18,"Produced a series of strong and deadly tornadoes that struck areas in and around Camilla, Meigs, and Omega, Georgia. Weaker tornadoes impacted other states."
2000 Fort Worth tornado,"March 28, 2000",U.S. South,10,2,"Small outbreak produced an F3 that hit downtown Fort Worth, Texas, severely damaging skyscrapers and killing two. Another F3 caused major damage in Arlington and Grand Prairie."
2000 Easter Sunday tornado outbreak,"April 23, 2000","Oklahoma, Texas, Louisiana, Arkansas",33,0,
"2000 Brady, Nebraska tornado","May 17, 2000",Nebraska,1,0,"Highly photographed F3 passed near Brady, Nebraska."
2000 Granite Falls tornado,"July 25, 2000","Granite Falls, Minnesota",1,1,"F4 struck Granite Falls, causing major damage and killing one person."

Answer (score 0):

To extract year from "Dates" column , as **object** type use

```
da['Year'] = da['Dates'].apply(lambda x: x[-4:])
```

If you want to use it as **int** then , you could do following operations after doing the step above

```
da['Year']=pd.to_numeric(da['Year'])
```

Comment: Thanks , the first line gave me an error 
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Mak2006 the Dates column is a string , isn't it. It works fine for  me https://imgur.com/a/EH85kOR

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a string, and not working for me yet

Comment: @Mak2006 if the issue remain unsolved , i would suggest you to add the data n question above in a formatted way as https://imgur.com/a/vAfBNxB